# Custom security Realm in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running a servlet based web application on google app engine.
I have stored user credentials in an entity called "login" like username,password,role name as properties.
Now I have to configure security constraint in web.xml with role names( have 4 roles) how can I verify the user role against  login.role  stored in datastore?

I read app engine does not support role other than admin is it so?
any workaround for this?  like JDBCRealm can I write my own customRealm?

-regards
 Ma

Comment: Those are appengine roles not application roles. You have to do it yourself at the beginning of your servlets.